# Github Copilot configuration fails for neovim

Tags: chatbot, neovim

Github copilot configuration in neovim fails.

I tried to use Github copilot in neovim on windows using [this](https://github.com/github/copilot.vim) documentation. After cloning repo, I wrote :Copilot setup in neovim but I got the following error
`Not an editor command: Copilot setup`
[image: error sc]
How to fix this

Comment: what does this say? `:checkhealth Copilot`